# Batch Convert TXT to XLS Using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, batch-file, text

I am trying to convert a directory full of .txt files to .xls using VBA. I am using the following code:

```
    Sub TXTconvertXLS()


    'Variables
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strDir As String

    'Directories
    strDir = "\\xx\xx\xx\xx\Desktop\Test\Test1\"
    strFile = Dir(strDir & "*.txt")

    'Loop
    Do While strFile <> ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strDir & strFile)
            With wb
                .SaveAs Replace(wb.FullName, ".txt", ".xls"), 50
                .Close True
            End With
        Set wb = Nothing
    Loop


    End Sub
```

The issue is: when I run it, it immediately states that there is already a file with the name it's trying to save with in the directory. The name it shows even has a .xls extension, even if there are assuredly no .xls's in the directory yet! Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

Comment: You seem to be missing `strFile = Dir` before `Loop`. Without it you are reprocessing the same TXT file. (see [Dir Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk008ty4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx))

Comment: bro, that's something you had to find out by yourself!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be missing `strFile = Dir` before `Loop`. Without it you are reprocessing the same TXT file.

```
    Do While strFile <> ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strDir & strFile)
            With wb
                .SaveAs Replace(wb.FullName, ".txt", ".xls"), 50
                .Close False   '<-already saved in the line directly above
            End With
        Set wb = Nothing
        strFile = Dir   '<- stuffs the next filename into strFile
    Loop
```

See [Dir Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk008ty4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)